# Mongoose model not saving after array splice

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose model with an array property that has a nested array property. The console.logs in the following code show exactly the data I'm expecting, however, the data is not persisted to the database and I have no clue why...

```
self.findByCustomerId(customerId, function (err, order) {
    if (err) done(err, null);
    console.log('Toppings before splice: ',order.lines[lineIdx].toppings);
    order.lines[lineIdx].toppings.splice(toppingIdx, 1);
    order.updated = new Date();

    // NOTE: This line causes the order.save to work
    order.markModified('lines');

    order.save(function (err) {
        if (err) done(err, null);
        console.log('Toppings after splice: ',order.lines[lineIdx].toppings);
        done(null,"OK");
    });
});
```

So everything is working perfectly but the final database persistence bit. What am I missing?

Thanks for your help, I'm lost.

Comment: Can you update you question to include the schema for `order`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needed order.markModified('lines'). I added the code to the original post. Adding this caused the model to save correctly.